Are questions about specific analytic theories and psycho-therapeutic approaches in pastoral counseling on topic?
If the question is asking about the intersection of theology and psychology, would it best be asked here or on C.SE? For instance, let's suppose I asked this question:

Do any existing pastoral counseling programs take into effect how the
  theological framework concerning the doctrine of free will affects the
  counselor's therapeutic approach? For instance, an institution that
  gravitates towards theological determinism (such as Calvinism in
  the Christian tradition) might be more likely to adopt an approach
  based on radical behaviorism such as CBA (e.g. ACT, which
  has an underlying worldview of functional contextualism; or
  functional analytic psychotherapy), while an institution that leans
  towards theological indeterminism/libertarianism (such as Buddhism or 
  Pelagianism and Arminianism in the Christian tradition) might
  feel more comfortable with standard CBT approaches.
From my experience, most pastoral counseling programs seem to teach
  some form of CBT without considering how the underlying worldview of
  the therapeutic approach conflicts (or agrees) with the theological
  ideologies of the institution and thus might create unintended
  counter-transference. Has anyone dealt with this in scholarly
  publications or studies? Do any institutions who teach pastoral
  counseling directly address this issue?


This sounds like an interesting question, but I think it is off topic for this site.
If you have a question about a specific approach, such as how cognitive behavioral therapy differs from alternative approaches, that could be on topic. However the question is really about pastoral programs, and how they choose therapeutic methods. I suspect you wouldn't find an answer to this in any mainstream journal related to cognitive science; you would have to ask the pastoral programs.
From a practical standpoint, I think it is unlikely that many of readers would have the expertise to answer this question. So even if the community decides that it is on topic, I have doubts that it will actually get a satisfactory response.

I was sort of thinking that. I asked the same question at C.SE and they decided it would be on topic, so I asked it there. But I figured I'd see what response I got in both locations. I appreciate your honest feedback.
